# How to send a mail with BCC to some recipients in Odoo 8?

Tags: python-2.7, email, gmail, odoo, odoo-8

I have created a module to send Blind Carbon Copy to specific users. To do this I have only inherited some models and modified a few lines:

**Model email.template**

I have added the next field:

```
email_bcc = fields.Char(string='Bcc',
                        help='Blind carbon copy message recipients')
```

And I have modified the following methods:

*generate_email_batch*, to modify the following line:

```
fields = ['subject', 'body_html', 'email_from', 'email_to', 'partner_to', 'email_cc', 'reply_to']
```

And turn it into the next one:

```
fields = ['subject', 'body_html', 'email_from', 'email_to', 'partner_to', 'email_cc', 'email_bcc', 'reply_to']
```

*generate_recipients_batch*, to modify the following line:

```
mails = tools.email_split(values.pop('email_to', '')) + tools.email_split(values.pop('email_cc', ''))
```

And turn it into the next one:

```
mails = tools.email_split(values.pop('email_to', '')) + tools.email_split(values.pop('email_cc', '')) + tools.email_split(values.pop('email_bcc', ''))
```

**Model mail.mail**

I have also added a field:

```
email_bcc = fields.Char(string='Bcc',
                        help='Blind carbon copy message recipients')
```

And modified the method `send`, to modify this line:

```
msg = ir_mail_server.build_email(
    email_from=mail.email_from,
    email_to=email.get('email_to'),
    subject=email.get('subject'),
    body=email.get('body'),
    body_alternative=email.get('body_alternative'),
    email_cc=tools.email_split(mail.email_cc),
    reply_to=mail.reply_to,
    attachments=attachments,
    message_id=mail.message_id,
    references=mail.references,
    object_id=mail.res_id and ('%s-%s' % (mail.res_id, mail.model)),
    subtype='html',
    subtype_alternative='plain',
    headers=headers
)
```

And turn it into the next one:

```
msg = ir_mail_server.build_email(
    email_from=mail.email_from,
    email_to=email.get('email_to'),
    subject=email.get('subject'),
    body=email.get('body'),
    body_alternative=email.get('body_alternative'),
    email_cc=tools.email_split(mail.email_cc),
    email_bcc=tools.email_split(mail.email_bcc),
    reply_to=mail.reply_to,
    attachments=attachments,
    message_id=mail.message_id,
    references=mail.references,
    object_id=mail.res_id and ('%s-%s' % (mail.res_id, mail.model)),
    subtype='html',
    subtype_alternative='plain',
    headers=headers
)
```

In both models, I am totally overwriting the methods (I was not able to find the way to modify them with a *super*).

**The problem**

I've created an email template to check `email_bcc`, and I call from code the method `send_mail` of `email.template`:

```
mails_sent &= et_pool.send_mail(
    self.env.cr, 1, template.id,
    user.id, force_send=True, context=ctx
)
```

First of all, when the mail is sent, I get this error in log:

*openerp.addons.email_template.email_template: Failed to render template  using values {'format_tz':  at 0x7f170051a8c0>, 'ctx': {'lang': 'es_ES', 'tz': 'Europe/Madrid', 'search_default_my_sale_orders_filter': 1, 'params': {'action': 318}, 'uid': 1}, 'user': res.users(1,), 'object': res.users(2,)}*

However, the mail is being sent rightly. But something surprising is always happening, I put an example to make you understand better:

My outgoing mail server is configured to send mails from the address **sender@gmail.com**. The email template has the address **to@gmail.com** in the `email_to` field, and the address **bcc@gmail.com** in the `email_bcc` field.

After I sent the email, if I log in Google account **to@gmail.com**, and I go to *Inbox*, I can see the email, but I can read that **sender@gmail.com** sent the email, that it was sent to me, **and that a blind carbon copy was sent to bcc@gmail.com**!

How is this possible? It seems that my module has worked well and sent the email in BCC to **bcc@gmail.com**, but why the **to@gmail.com** owner can see that fact???

Anyone can help me please?

If someone is interested in checking the module, it is here:

https://github.com/forvas/social/tree/8.0

Its name is **mail_bcc**.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, How can i solve this @forvas

Comment: I haven't solved it yet :/

Comment: I am also stucked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem recently and I don't think it's the module's fault, but Google's SMTP server (I assume you configured one because of the @gmail.com addresses). When I switched from GMail to our company's mail server, the BCC field was properly handled, so the mail was sent to the BCC recipient but it was not visible to the people in TO and CC.

Comment: Thank you for answering! As you wrote, I am using Google's SMTP server as the outgoing mail server. Which could be the problem?

Comment: Yes exactly. I changed nothing in the code (using the email_cc_bcc module though, which had the same behaviour as you described).Maybe it is possible to configure it in the GMail-Account's settings.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to do the same thing, to send messages with Bcc, I have used this code, but I don't receive any email into the bcc email.I am using Gmail SMTP